# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable error in python

Tags: python, numpy, callable

I was converting LU decomposition matlab code into python.

But while I was doing it I encountered with this error

> `'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

this error occurs when I tried to test my code. Here is my code and can anyone help with this problem?? I'm waiting for your help.

```
import numpy as np

def LU(a):
    [m,m]=a.shape

    for k in range(0,m-1,1):
        a[k+1:m-1,k]=a[k+1:m-1,k]/a(k,k)
        a[k+1:m-1,k+1:m-1]=a[k+1:m-1,k+1:m-1]-a[k+1:m-1,k]*a[k,k+1:m-1]
    L=np.eye(m,m)+np.tril(a,-1)
    U=np.triu(a)
    return [L,U]

b=np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])

LU(b)
```

Comment: You should always include the full traceback in your question, rather than just the last line. This makes it much easier to see where in your code the error is occurring (as others have  said, the issue is that you've used round rather than square brackets in `a(k,k)`).

Answer (score 5):

The error is occurring because you have used the wrong kind of braces on the 4th line of your function.

```
a[k+1:m-1,k]=a[k+1:m-1,k]/a(k,k)
```

should be corrected to

```
a[k+1:m-1,k]=a[k+1:m-1,k]/a[k,k]
```

i.e. the `()` braces should be replaced by `[]`. The error is occurring because `[]` braces suggest an indexing operation, whereas `()` braces suggest a function call.